# More efficient Linq-to-SQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am looking for a more efficient way to do this...(see below)... I have to perform it seven times as I have seven feature articles. The id I am feeding off is the page id (aka featurearticles.fk_pageID_item1 featurearticles.fk_pageID_item2).

I am ok with doing a table join and not selecting * as it were. I am also ok with making a temporary object to hold information.

```
DataAccess.Page pgf1 = (from p in db.Pages
where p.pageID == featurearticles.fk_pageID_item1
select p).FirstOrDefault();

PageArticle paf1 =(from pa in db.PageArticles
where pa.page_art_pageID == pgf1.pageID &&
pa.page_art_isCurrent ==true
select pa).FirstOrDefault();

Article af1 = (from a in db.Articles
where a.articleID == paf1.page_art_articleID
select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

1. gets a page.
2. gets the current version.
3. gets the info for that version.

I am stuck with this table layout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the credit for this goes to astander.

```
Article af1 = (from p in db.Pages
               join pa in db.PageArticles on p.pageID equals pa.page_art_pageID
               join a in db.Articles on pa.page_art_articleID equals a.articleID
               where p.pageID == featurearticles.fk_pageID_item1
               && pa.page_art_isCurrent == true
               select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

You should be able to use this query as a drop in replacement for what you already have.

Comment: && pa.page_art_isCurrent == true

Comment: OK, that's probably because your page_art_isCurrent  is Nullable<bool>. I guessed it was bool.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this. These are all inner joins, and I am not sure if this is entirely what you require? If not let me know.

```
var tp = from p in Pages
    join pa in PageArticles on p.pageID equals pa.page_art_pageID
    join a in Articles on pa.page_art_articleID equals a.articleID
    where p.pageID == featurearticles.fk_pageID_item1
    && pa.page_art_isCurrent
    select new { p, pa, a };
```

I can also change the new select to what ever fields you require.

Comment: If you want to fix your comment to do exactly what he is already doing, edit your comment to mine, then I'll delete mine.

Comment: You want me to change the *select* and the *FirstOrDefault*?

Comment: You can change whatever you like or leave it as is - there's nothing wrong with your answer. I wanted to offer him an alternative solution that does *exactly* what he wants so he can use it immediately without having to worry about the compile errors he'll get if he copies and pastes your solution. But basically I just took your answer and fixed it up so it compiles with the classes he has. Maybe it's better he has both options so he can see which is best for his situation.

Comment: PS: it's not just the select and the FirstOrDefault that I changed. Your table names also need a `db.` in front of them if your code is to work as a drop in replacement.

Comment: Yes, I tested this with local classes I created in a quick solution, so I did now include the *db.*

Comment: thanks astander & Mark. I am new to linq to sql and could not figure out how to join the tables. Both your answers were great. ;)